# Java method returns the given variable instead of the result

Tags: java

I am new in Java, I am trying to make a program for a wallet the first method should return the wallet current money which it does,but the second one which is supposed to add money to the wallet and return the result of the addition keeps returning me the value I am giving to add(addmoney).

```
package wallet;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Wallet {
 double money;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  Wallet w = new Wallet();
  Double money = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.println(walletbalance(money));
  Double addmoney = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.println(w.moneyaddition(addmoney));
 }
 public static double walletbalance(double bal) {
  return bal;
 }
 public double moneyaddition(double added) {
  return money = added + money;
 }
}
```

Comment: you should set money inside `walletbalance`.

Comment: why ya've written `return money = added + money;` ? It should be rather: `return added + money;`

Answer (score 0):

The observed behavior is result of a side-effect. That is, you expected `moneyaddition` to return the result of `money+added` and wonder why the function returned just the `added` value instead of the sum. There's nothing wrong with the function your looking at, *but* in the prior call to `walletbalance` you've never set the `money` member, so 0 + `added` makes `added`. You need to fix the setter for this property, then it works:

```
public static double walletbalance(double bal) {
    money = bal;
    return bal;
}
```